# Natural Sort version numbers in a table in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sorting

I've written a PowerShell function to query for Citrix Receiver versions: https://gist.github.com/aaronparker/8204e49405a78245301dae1ebaf1df71

This returns an array/table that looks like this:

```
Platform                                         Version
--------                                         -------
Receiver for Linux                               13.0
Receiver for Linux                               13.1
Receiver for Linux                               13.2
Receiver for Linux                               13.2.1
Receiver for Linux                               13.3
Receiver for Linux                               13.4
Receiver for Linux                               13.5
Receiver for Linux                               13.6
Receiver for Linux                               13.7
Receiver for Linux                               13.8
Receiver for Mac                                 11.9.15
Receiver for Mac                                 12.1.100
Receiver for Mac                                 12.2
Receiver for Mac                                 12.3
Receiver for Mac                                 12.4
Receiver for Mac                                 12.5
Receiver for Mac                                 12.6
Receiver for Mac                                 12.7
Receiver for Mac                                 12.8.1
Receiver for Windows                             4.10.1
Receiver for Windows                             4.3.100
Receiver for Windows                             4.5
Receiver for Windows                             4.6
Receiver for Windows                             4.7
Receiver for Windows                             4.8
```

I'd like to perform a natural search on the Version property. I can do that successfully if only sorting the Versions property (or sorting an array that includes only version numbers), e.g.:

```
$SortNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
$array.Version | Sort-Object $SortNatural
```

However, this becomes more difficult when sorting the entire table. I'd like to sort on Platform and then Version. I can, of course, do something like this:

```
$array | Sort-Object -Property Platform, @{Expression = '$_.Version'; Ascending = $True}
```

But this doesn't provide the correct sort. I'm trying to understand how to use the natural sort using an Expression with Sort-Object.

Any pointers or alternate suggestions for achieving my desired sort approach?

Comment: Cast your version values as `[Version]` objects and they'll compare as you are probably expecting.

Comment: Brilliant! So simple. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking to do the same, here's how it's fixed, thanks to @Bill_Stewart. Full code in the Gist link above.

```
$Receivers += $ReceiverLinks | Select-Object @{Name = "Platform"; Expression = {$_.innerText -replace $RegExVersion}}, `
                @{Name = "Version"; Expression = {[Version]$($_.innerText -replace $RegExNumbers)}}
$Receivers | Sort-Object -Property Platform, @{Expression = 'Version'; Descending = $True}
```